# AWS Lambda - Support for Multiple Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to use AWS Lambda for transforming the messages of different types to some other type. It would be complex transformation which means, there would be a lot of rules which defines the transformation. So, to keep the code clean, I wanted to keep different files instead of single files in AWS Lambda. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'keep different files instead of single files'. Can you elaborate more

Comment: if a single file is not possible to manage can you try creating lambda functions for each transformation and call from a general lambda function by passing your complex messages ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok , so basically you wanted to have multiple files probably each file having a different transformation technique inside this -

At the end you want to send multiple files to a lambda function as a zip and use these files inside the lambda_handler() function .

You need to create all your files inside a directory in such a way that they can be imported in other files easily and zip your lambda function and use it.
Before creating a zip ensure that your code is actually working locally.

[Creating a Deployment Package (Python)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

Read this for more, assuming you are using python

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a container with all the files and then call the handle function using lambda?

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer I try to do this, but AWS's lambda image, is unable to find the handler. Not sure what's the issue.